# How to make postgres search fast

Tags: sql, postgresql, bigdata

I have a Postgresql-database with more than 100 billion rows in one table.

The table schema is as follow:

```
 id_1                   | integer                     |           | not null | 
 id_2                   | bigint                      |           | not null | 
 created_at             | timestamp without time zone |           | not null | 
 id_3                   | bigint                      |           |          | 
 char1                  | character varying(20)       |           | not null | 
 lang                   | character(6)                |           | not null | 
 gps                    | point                       |           |          | 
 some_dat               | character varying(140)[]    |           |          | 
 JSON                   | jsonb                       |           | not null |
```

- I'm trying to search inside the JSON object and sort the data by the JSON object but the problem is that it takes too much time for sorting and returning the data.
- Also when sorting the data by `created_at` for example, it takes also time for the result.

I'm trying to make my application as a real-time as I can.

I have 2 indexing for `id_1` and `id_2`

Also, I tried to use materialized view for each (`id`) but the problem is updating the materialized view takes much time also.
Any suggestions please?

I'm running PostgreSQL 10.3, on a Linux server with SSD and 128 GB of ram.

Thanks,

Comment: What is the column which is being used in your search queries? Can it be any?

Comment: Depending on the queries you do on the json data putting a gin index on that column will help, see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/datatype-json.html#JSON-INDEXING for more help with optimizing queries post the specific queries and the explain analyze output for those queries. Have you tuned postgresql for your hardware?

Comment: @MacakM yes, any column.

Comment: @MohamedSaad if it can be any column, than indexes will not help you because you would have to use them everywhere. Are you open to other databases or does it have to be PostgreSQL?

Comment: @MacakM, no I can use any databases. I tried Cassandra but didn't do the job for me.

Comment: @Eelke The problem is json indexing will take too much size on the disk.
what do you mean by `Have you tuned postgresql for your hardware?`

Comment: @MohamedSaad you can try to use VoltDB, it is designed to handle this type of use cases.

Comment: @MohamedSaad, sounds like a no, in postgresql.conf  there are settings that influence memory usage. The most important one is `shared_buffers` which defaults to 128MB while on your system 32GB would be a better starting value. You also want to bump up `work_mem`, `maintenance_work_mem` and `temp_buffers`. Also set `random_page_cost` to the same value as `seq_page_cost` as SSD don't care about random or sequential.

Comment: @MohamedSaad, yes indexes on json can be big but they also help a lot when they work for the kind of queries you do this is often the trade of you will have to make. Maybe mongodb or elasticsearch will work better for you as they are both geared to storing and searching json.

Comment: @Eelke
here's my configuration 
[
max_connections = 1000
shared_buffers = 10GB
effective_cache_size = 30GB
work_mem = 10485kB
maintenance_work_mem = 2GB
min_wal_size = 1GB
max_wal_size = 2GB
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.7
wal_buffers = 16MB
default_statistics_target = 100
random_page_cost = 1.1
]
I already set it on my server.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort a query result with an expression like this:

```
ORDER BY expr1, expr2, ...
```

You need the following index to speed up the sorting:

```
CREATE INDEX ON atable ((expr1), (expr2), ...);
```

If that does not work because the expressions contain functions that are not `IMMUTABLE`, you cannot speed up the sort with an index. In that case, consider rewriting your query with `IMMUTABLE` expressions.

Comment: I'm sure it is working. But since your question doesn't show details like the query you want to speed up, it is hard to help you.